# jQuery .on('click') event only working once when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having an issue with an on click event only working once - it should be toggling the `.p-active` class, and instead only adds it.

There is content that is dynamically added after the click using `lighttooltip.js`, but I don't think that it should be affecting the `toggleClass` function inside of my click event, but it is somehow and I need to work around that.

I've tried changing the on click's delegation using `document`, `"body"`, `".hotspots"`, all of which doesn't work. Using `"div"` and `".hotspot"` for delegation allows for the class to be toggled on, but not toggled off.

I did notice however that after removing all the `.LiteTooltip` jQuery code (below the on click function, this is the content that is dynamically added to the page after a 'hotspot' is clicked) that my on click functions as intended.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. I've shortened the code a bit, as there are originally 30 "hotspots", but lowered to 3 to make the code easier to read.

**Note:** *What is NOT being toggled is the hotspot number itself - it should change from pink to white when toggled.*

```css
/**** look inside tooltip CSS ****/

div#look-inside .et_pb_row {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 1500px !important;
}

#tooltip-clickoutside {
  /*z-index: 10;*/
}

.litetooltip-wrapper {
  font: inherit;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-arrow {
  border: none !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content {
  padding: 2em 10px !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  min-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template h4 {
  font-size: 250%;
  color: #004023;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template .content {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 2.5% 2.5% !important;
  display: block;
  /* text-align: center; */
  background: #f2edde;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both !important;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.template p {
  background: #f2edde !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  float: none !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.redhotspot {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 103;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #d11947;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.redhotspot.p-active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d11947;
}

.look-inside {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  /* actual width of image*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 101;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.look-inside .img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
  /* image-height / width * 100 */
}

.look-inside img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 102;
}

.item-gallery img {
  display: none;
}

.item-gallery img.p-active {
  display: block;
}

.left-arrow:before {
  content: "\34";
}

.right-arrow:before {
  content: "\35";
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  top: 44px;
  top: 2em;
  height: 180px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  color: #9aa2b0;
}

.left-arrow:hover {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 160px);
  left: calc(50% - 160px);
  color: #d11947;
}

.right-arrow:hover {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% + 60px);
  left: calc(50% + 60px);
  color: #d11947;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% + 50px);
  left: calc(50% + 50px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.left-arrow:before,
.right-arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'ETmodules';
  font-size: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 177px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both !important;
}

.item-gallery.single-logo {
  width: 212px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .redhotspot {
    font-size: 17px !important;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/look-inside/litetooltip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/look-inside/litetooltip.min.js"></script>


<div class="look-inside">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img alt="Look Inside" src="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/Breckenridge.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="hotspots">
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot1">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 20%; left: 44.5%; cursor: pointer;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot2">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 31.5%; left: 32.5%; cursor: pointer;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot3">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 43.5%; left: 18%; cursor: pointer;">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hotspot" id="tooltips"></div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //on hotspot click convert more than one image into gallery with arrows
    var int = false;

    $("div").on("click", ".redhotspot", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'), "clicked!");
      $(this).toggleClass("p-active");
    });
  });


  //All tooltip content lives below
  jQuery('#ihotspot1').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot1">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
      '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
  jQuery('#ihotspot2').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot2">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2.1ExteriorHydrochannel.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Exterior Hydro Channel" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Exterior Hydro Channel</h4>' +
      '<p>Exterior Hydro Channel is considered the jack of all trades when it comes to basement waterproofing. It collects any water that reaches your basement walls on the outside of the home and directs it to the sump pump, where it is routed out of and away from the foundation. This is just one facet of the entire system that is used to ensure the foundation, basement and interior of the home stay dry.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
  jQuery('#ihotspot3').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot3">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/3.1InteriorHydroChannel.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Interior Hydro Channel" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Interior Hydro Channel & Drainage System</h4>' +
      '<p>Interior Hydro Channel acts as a natural passageway for water to drain to the sump bucket. This aspect of the foundation waterproofing system is placed between the basement floor and walls to ensure any water that travels under the basement floor has a path back outside. The interior hydro channel acts as an extra layer of insurance for finishing the lower level of a home.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
</script>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Please check the updated jQuery lines. This will work for you I guess.

```css
/**** look inside tooltip CSS ****/

div#look-inside .et_pb_row {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 1500px !important;
}

#tooltip-clickoutside {
  /*z-index: 10;*/
}

.litetooltip-wrapper {
  font: inherit;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-arrow {
  border: none !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content {
  padding: 2em 10px !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  min-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template h4 {
  font-size: 250%;
  color: #004023;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template .content {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 2.5% 2.5% !important;
  display: block;
  /* text-align: center; */
  background: #f2edde;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both !important;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.template p {
  background: #f2edde !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  float: none !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.redhotspot {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 103;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #d11947;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.redhotspot.p-active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d11947;
}

.look-inside {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  /* actual width of image*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 101;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.look-inside .img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
  /* image-height / width * 100 */
}

.look-inside img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 102;
}

.item-gallery img {
  display: none;
}

.item-gallery img.p-active {
  display: block;
}

.left-arrow:before {
  content: "\34";
}

.right-arrow:before {
  content: "\35";
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  top: 44px;
  top: 2em;
  height: 180px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  color: #9aa2b0;
}

.left-arrow:hover {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 160px);
  left: calc(50% - 160px);
  color: #d11947;
}

.right-arrow:hover {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% + 60px);
  left: calc(50% + 60px);
  color: #d11947;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% + 50px);
  left: calc(50% + 50px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.left-arrow:before,
.right-arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'ETmodules';
  font-size: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 177px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both !important;
}

.item-gallery.single-logo {
  width: 212px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .redhotspot {
    font-size: 17px !important;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/look-inside/litetooltip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/look-inside/litetooltip.min.js"></script>


<div class="look-inside">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img alt="Look Inside" src="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/Breckenridge.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="hotspots">
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot1">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 20%; left: 44.5%; cursor: pointer;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot2">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 31.5%; left: 32.5%; cursor: pointer;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot3">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 43.5%; left: 18%; cursor: pointer;">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hotspot" id="tooltips"></div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //on hotspot click convert more than one image into gallery with arrows
    var int = false;

   $(".redhotspot").click(function (e) {
     $(this).toggleClass("p-active");
     $(this).parents().siblings().children().removeClass("p-active");
   });
  });


  //All tooltip content lives below
  jQuery('#ihotspot1').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot1">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
      '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
  jQuery('#ihotspot2').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot2">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2.1ExteriorHydrochannel.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Exterior Hydro Channel" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Exterior Hydro Channel</h4>' +
      '<p>Exterior Hydro Channel is considered the jack of all trades when it comes to basement waterproofing. It collects any water that reaches your basement walls on the outside of the home and directs it to the sump pump, where it is routed out of and away from the foundation. This is just one facet of the entire system that is used to ensure the foundation, basement and interior of the home stay dry.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
  jQuery('#ihotspot3').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot3">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/3.1InteriorHydroChannel.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Interior Hydro Channel" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Interior Hydro Channel & Drainage System</h4>' +
      '<p>Interior Hydro Channel acts as a natural passageway for water to drain to the sump bucket. This aspect of the foundation waterproofing system is placed between the basement floor and walls to ensure any water that travels under the basement floor has a path back outside. The interior hydro channel acts as an extra layer of insurance for finishing the lower level of a home.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: while `e.stopPropagation();` does allow for the hotspot numbers to toggle correctly, it stops my dynamic content "Litetooltip" from being loaded

Comment: Thats beacuse of the LiteToolTip trigger event is set on click of the parent div. Have to configure the trigger event on click of the 'redhotspot' div. Finding the right way.

Comment: thank you for the help, I look forward to your findings.

Comment: I've updated the code. Let me know if any glitch pops up.

Comment: That works! How did something that seemed so complicated, become some simple? That's crazy! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I did update your code to include option to remove active class from sibling hotspots when a new hotspot is clicked.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, that's good. And most welcome to you, I appreciate your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `e.stopPropagation();` to stop the click event from bubbling up the DOM and triggering a click on the parent div:

```css
/**** look inside tooltip CSS ****/

div#look-inside .et_pb_row {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 1500px !important;
}

#tooltip-clickoutside {
  /*z-index: 10;*/
}

.litetooltip-wrapper {
  font: inherit;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-arrow {
  border: none !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content {
  padding: 2em 10px !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  min-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template h4 {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #004023;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template .content {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 2.5% 2.5% !important;
  display: block;
  /* text-align: center; */
  background: #f2edde;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both !important;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.template p {
  background: #f2edde !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  float: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.redhotspot {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 103;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #d11947;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.redhotspot.p-active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d11947;
}

.look-inside {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  /* actual width of image*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 101;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.look-inside .img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
  /* image-height / width * 100 */
}

.look-inside img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 102;
}

.item-gallery img {
  display: none;
}

.item-gallery img.p-active {
  display: block;
}

.left-arrow:before {
  content: "\34";
}

.right-arrow:before {
  content: "\35";
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  top: 44px;
  top: 2em;
  height: 180px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  color: #9aa2b0;
}

.left-arrow:hover {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 160px);
  left: calc(50% - 160px);
  color: #d11947;
}

.right-arrow:hover {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% + 60px);
  left: calc(50% + 60px);
  color: #d11947;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: -webkit-calc(50% + 50px);
  left: calc(50% + 50px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.left-arrow:before,
.right-arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'ETmodules';
  font-size: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 177px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both !important;
}

.item-gallery.single-logo {
  width: 212px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .redhotspot {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/look-inside/litetooltip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/look-inside/litetooltip.min.js"></script>


<div class="look-inside">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img alt="Look Inside" src="https://paynefhstage.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/Breckenridge.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="hotspots">
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot1">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 80%; left: 44.5%; cursor: pointer;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot2">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 91.5%; left: 32.5%; cursor: pointer;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hotspot" id="ihotspot3">
      <div class="redhotspot" style="top: 83.5%; left: 18%; cursor: pointer;">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hotspot" id="tooltips"></div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //on hotspot click convert more than one image into gallery with arrows
    var int = false;

    $("div").on("click", ".redhotspot", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'), "clicked!");
      $(this).toggleClass("p-active");
    });
  });


  //All tooltip content lives below
  jQuery('#ihotspot1').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot1">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="Waterproofing" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
      '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
  jQuery('#ihotspot2').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot2">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2.1ExteriorHydrochannel.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Exterior Hydro Channel" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Exterior Hydro Channel</h4>' +
      '<p>Exterior Hydro Channel is considered the jack of all trades when it comes to basement waterproofing. It collects any water that reaches your basement walls on the outside of the home and directs it to the sump pump, where it is routed out of and away from the foundation. This is just one facet of the entire system that is used to ensure the foundation, basement and interior of the home stay dry.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
  jQuery('#ihotspot3').LiteTooltip({
    textalign: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 0,
    shadow: 0,
    container: 'tooltips',
    issticky: false,
    title: '<div class="template ihotspot3">' +
      '<div class="item-gallery">' +
      '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/3.1InteriorHydroChannel.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="Interior Hydro Channel" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="content">' +
      '<h4>Interior Hydro Channel & Drainage System</h4>' +
      '<p>Interior Hydro Channel acts as a natural passageway for water to drain to the sump bucket. This aspect of the foundation waterproofing system is placed between the basement floor and walls to ensure any water that travels under the basement floor has a path back outside. The interior hydro channel acts as an extra layer of insurance for finishing the lower level of a home.</p>  ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: While `e.stopPropagation();` does allow for the hotspot numbers to toggle correctly, it stops my dynamic content from being loaded.